# Same footer div on different pages looks different

Tags: css, layout, styling, html

I just fixed one problem with the footer div I have, and made another one :)

Currently, I have the footer broken broken on this page:

http://www.comehike.com/hikes/scheduled_hike.php?hike_id=189

See how the footer goes across the entire page?

Now take a look here:

http://www.comehike.com/earn_money.php

The footer is across the entire page, and also has bigger letters.

Here is the styling for my footer that I think is used by both pages.  Although that thinking might be the problem here :)

```
/* styles for footer */

.footer
{
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;  
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:center;
    background: #fff;
    color: #462c1f;
    border: 10px solid #fff;  
}
.footer a, .footer span {
    color: #462c1f;
    font-size:85%;
}
.footer a {
    color: #7E9940;
    font-size:85%;
}

.footer a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #3f6b30;
}
```

Comment: You're right. Your footer div isn't in the correct container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the second case (which I think is correct) http://www.comehike.com/earn_money.php, has the `.footer` inside the `.mainBody`

The first case (http://www.comehike.com/hikes/scheduled_hike.php?hike_id=189) is outside!

That's why it is different.

The problem is not at the CSS (in this case) but more with the where the footer is at the html, which inherits styles from other containers.

Comment: +1 ... though I think of a footer as **not** part of the mainBody

Answer (score 2):

The footer is centered because with the border, it is the same width as the main section above it, and doesn't have any margin/padding outside of it affecting its placement.

As for the text size, the footer at http://www.comehike.com/hikes/scheduled_hike.php?hike_id=189 is inheriting the text size from the `body`, which has the style `font-size: 1em;`, and the footer at http://www.comehike.com/earn_money.php is inheriting the text size from `div#layout2.content`, where the `.content` class has the style `font-size: 13px;`

Answer (score 1):

I bet you close a div tag too early or something relatively simply like that. Try playing around with adding a `</div>` tag before and then after the footer, and see what this does. Alternately delete a `</div>` tag and see what this does. The route overlay may be a contributing factor, but it's hard to say without being able to debug this extensively to see.